# Adding a composed attrbiute

Tags: angular

Hi I just started working on my first angular 2 project and my first task is to port an existing andular 1 directive. What I need to do is set the attribute of an svg g element to 'translate(outerRadius, innerRadius)' where outerRadius and innerRadius are variables from my component. This is what I have tried:

```
<g [attr.transform]="translate(outerRadius, innerRadius)"></g>
```

This syntax gives me the following error:

[image]

This is my component code:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgStyle} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'donut-chart',
    templateUrl: './app/engager/components/donut-chart.component.html',
    directives: [NgStyle]
})
export class DonutChart implements OnInit {

    public outerRadius: number = 50;
    public innerRadius: number;

    ngOnInit() {
        const defaultRadius: number = 45;

        this.innerRadius = this.innerRadius < this.outerRadius ? this.innerRadius : defaultRadius;

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `<g [attr.transform]="'translate(' + outerRadius + ',' + innerRadius + ')'"></g>`

Comment: this worked thanx add it as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Typescript's [template string](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html) interpolation:

```
<g [attr.transform]="translateAsString"></g>

export class DonutChart implements OnInit {

  public outerRadius: number = 50;
  public innerRadius: number;
  public translateAsString: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    const defaultRadius: number = 45;

    this.innerRadius = this.innerRadius < this.outerRadius ? this.innerRadius : defaultRadius;
    this.translateAsString = `translate(${this.outerRadius}, ${this.innerRadius})`;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this tag `<g [attr.transform]="translate(outerRadius, innerRadius)"></g>`, `translate(outerRadius, innerRadius)` is interpreted by angular as an expression. `outerRadius` and `innerRadius` are valid variable but `translate` is not.

Try

```
<g [attr.transform]="'translate(' + outerRadius + ',' + innerRadius + ')'"></g>
```

This will render as `<g transform="translate(50, 45)"></g>`